# Quickblox shares users across applications

Tags: android, ios, mobile, quickblox

I'm using quickblox to power most of my applications.I noticed that Quickblox shares the users table across all my applications which are under the same account.So if a user registered in my app (A) , he won't be able to register in my app (B), because that email account is already registered . am I missing something here ? or is it a bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done by design (old design) and we face a lot of performance issues with this approach (internally).

At the moment, you can use single user to login in different apps.

In next version(in ~4-6 weeks), one user will be able to log in only to *single* application under their credentials.
So you will be able to create 2 users with the same credentials in 2 apps.

You can check QuickBlox updates here https://quickblox.com/blog

Comment: that's a shame , well my only option now is to distribute my apps across new accounts right ? ok is there a way to export users table ?

Comment: @Igor Khomenko , Is  there any updates available regarding create 2 users with the same credentials in 2 apps?